# In an Observable notebook, unable to use a function from an npm library, perhaps because unable to import a function from the library's dependency

Tags: javascript, requirejs, levenberg-marquardt, observablehq

I want to reproduce the [example](https://github.com/mljs/levenberg-marquardt/tree/master) in [this npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@msitko/ml-levenberg-marquardt) in an Observable notebook. I run the following in a cell and a block:

```
fit_data = {
  let data = {
    x: [0, 1, 2],
    y: [1, 1, 1]
  }
  return data
}
```

```
{
    const LM = require('ml-levenberg-marquardt@2.1.1/lib/index.js').catch(() => window["_interopDefault"]);
    function sinFunction([a, b]) {
    return (t) => a * Math.sin(b * t);
  }

  const options = {
    damping: 1.5,
    gradientDifference: 10e-2,
    maxIterations: 100,
    errorTolerance: 10e-3
  };

  let fittedParams = levenbergMarquardt(fit_data, sinFunction, options);
  return fittedParams
}
```

and I get the error message `TypeError: isArray is not a function`, which I suspect is [this function](https://github.com/mljs/levenberg-marquardt/blob/master/src/index.js#L1) failing to be imported from the library's dependency.

I am importing the library by following [this guide](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/module-require-debugger).

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, I guess you misspelled the import method name. Another suggestion is to break into cells. Here are the cells that worked for me

Here is how you import it

```js
LM = await require('ml-levenberg-marquardt@2.1.1/lib/index.js').catch(
  () => window["_interopDefault"]
)
```

Here is how you use it

```js
{
  const options = {
    damping: 1.5,
    gradientDifference: 10e-2,
    maxIterations: 100,
    errorTolerance: 10e-3
  };

  let fittedParams = LM(fit_data, sinFunction, options);
  return fittedParams;
}
```

```js
fit_data = {
  let data = {
    x: [0, 1, 2],
    y: [1, 1, 1]
  };
  return data;
}
```

```js
function sinFunction([a, b]) {
  return t => a * Math.sin(b * t);
}
```